# Capture the URL in the javascript initiated HTTP GET/POST requests using selenium

Tags: selenium

I'm using selenium for automating a procedure I frequently use on a site.

When I press on specific element on the site it runs some complex javascript code that eventually downloads a csv file using HTTP GET request.
I can see that the URL of this request looks like: www.somesite.com/somepage.php?**token=RAPO09834HROLQ340HGIE309W**&....

My question is: how can I get the token in this URL with selenium? (I need it for executing other HTTP GET requests for extracting more data from the site)

I am using Firefox driver on windows.

I tried to search all the html, js, cookies I get from this site, the token is not there. (its probably generated by the javascript code before it does the HTTP request)

I understand this is some kind of session id token as all the javascript generated HTTP requests are using the same token during my session.

Comment: have you tried `driver.getCurrentURL()` maybe this gets you the full url with the token and so on. then you can extract that from the string?

Comment: I tried it, it gives me only the site domain.